# How to restore right characters encoding for the cyrillic phrase "Â ñòîðîíó Äîæäÿ"?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, id3

I have downloaded mp3 files with broken characters inside ID3 tags.
How to detect the original encoding of these symbols and how to convert them to the real UTF-8?

The phrase "Â ñòîðîíó Äîæäÿ" must look like "В сторону дождя" (russian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
pip install mutagen
cd music-dir/
find . -print0 | xargs -0 mid3iconv -eCP1251 --remove-v1
```